# PHP MySQLi Query returning null with valid syntax

Tags: php, syntax, mysqli, null

Ok so,

I have been trying to make a ticket system for my wxPanel in order to provide basic support for the application. Although I am easily able to make a database record with the provided code:

***PHP:***

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $date = date('D M H:i');

    $subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($subject);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($message);
    $ticket_id = 'TICK_'.rand(00000,99999);

    if (strlen($subject) === 0) {
        echo "Subject Invalid.";
    } elseif (strlen($message) === 0) {
        echo "Message Invalid.";
    } else {
        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(
        NULL,
        '".$ticket_id."',
        '".$_SESSION['user']."',
        '".$subject."',
        '1',
        '".$date."',
        '".$message."'
        )");
    }
    header('Location: /view-ticket?identifier='.$ticket_id);
}
```

Works fine...
Then there is this, which is ment to fetch the ticket records and display the titles one by one:

***PHP:***

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT `subject`,`ticket_id` FROM tickets WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['user']."'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $tickets = $row['subject'];
    $id = $row['ticket_id'];
}

foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
    echo '
    <a href="view-ticket?identifier='.$id.'"><h2>'.$ticket.'</h2></a>
    ';
}
```

This always returns NULL. And also none of this works either:

```
if (isset($_GET['identifier']) === false || empty($_GET['identifier']) === true) {
    header('Location: /tickets');
    exit();
}

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['identifier']);

$query = mysqli_query("SELECT `ticket_id`,`message`,`timestamp`,`status` FROM tickets WHERE `ticket_id` = '".$id."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $ticket_id = $row['ticket_id'];
    $message = $row['message'];
    $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $status = $row['status'];
}

foreach($message as $msg) {
    echo '
    <div class="ticket-message">
        <h2>'.$message.'</h2>
    </div>';
}
```

Thank you in advance!

p.s. Some of my code may be messy. Advice is always appreciated :)

Comment: For one thing, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` needs a DB connection parameter `$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($subject);` which should read as `$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$subject);` - `$con` being the DB connection variable. Plus, I don't know how you're connecting with the rest of your code. This `$query = mysqli_query("SELECT` should look something like `$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT...` - Your DB connection wouldn't happen to be `mysql_` by any chance, would it?

Comment: I am using the mysqli_connect, I wasn't aware that I needed to use a connection variable to directly interact with the database.

Comment: Yep and for so many reasons using `mysqli_*` functions. In the olden days of `mysql_`, once a connection was established, the functions didn't need it afterwards; all the more reasons for security reasons. So, doing that may very well fix all or most of the problems.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so during development. It will signal any errors found, if any.

Comment: It is also very dangerous to code INSERT's without naming the columns as well as providing the data. Some bright spark is bound to look at the table definition and decide to move column2 after columns4 and then at best your query breaks and at worst puts data into the wrong column which nobody realises for days or weeks and really messes up your database.

Comment: Ok, If I do a var_dump($query = mysqli_query("SELECT `ticket_id`,`message`,`timestamp`,`status` FROM tickets WHERE `ticket_id` = '".$id."'")); on this, I can see that it returns "NULL" any ideas @Fred-ii- ?

Comment: Ok thank you @RiggsFolly for the advice, I'll try to implement this into my client area as soon as I get this fixed...

Comment: Are you not passing DB connection to `$query = mysqli_query("SELECT...` like I suggested? If DB variable is `$con` do `$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT...` if you don't have one, create one.

Comment: Also try $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ticket_id,message,timestamp,status FROM tickets WHERE ticket_id = '$id' "); var_dump($result);  Just to remove any possible confusion about var_dumping the whole query statement.

Comment: Ok, I'm making some head-way here. I have found ALL functions missing the connection variable and I am now getting this: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 4 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) as a result. Make any sense why this would be the outcome?

Comment: @RiggsFolly doing a var dump var_dump($query); has returned the same array as a print_r.

Comment: That is a mysqli_result object. See http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php But as num_rows = 0 you have not got any rows in your result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the SELECT query working you are also going to have to look at the code that processes the results.

**If ticket_id identifies a unique row**

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ticket_id,message,timestamp,status 
                             FROM tickets WHERE ticket_id = '$id'");


$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$ticket_id = $row['ticket_id'];
$message   = $row['message'];
$timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
$status    = $row['status'];

echo '<div class="ticket-message"><h2>'.$message.'</h2></div>';
```

**If ticket_id does not identify a unique row**

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ticket_id,message,timestamp,status 
                             FROM tickets WHERE ticket_id = '$id'");

// initialise the arrays that hold multiple row results
$ticket_id[] = array();
$message[]   = array();
$timestamp[] = array();
$status[]    = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $ticket_id[] = $row['ticket_id'];
   $message[]   = $row['message'];
   $timestamp[] = $row['timestamp'];
   $status[]    = $row['status'];
}

foreach($message as $msg) {
   echo '<div class="ticket-message"><h2>'.$msg.'</h2></div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you both of you for helping, everything is up and running! Enjoy the rest of your evenings.

Comment: Ok, ran into one small problem

Comment: I have found that if I try to output $username or $timestamp it returns "Array".

Comment: I dont see any reference to $username but $timestamp is an array if you are using my amended code. It has to be as it contains data from multiple fetches

Comment: Well actually I may have assumed to much. As your query has a WHERE Ticket_id = '$id', if that identifies a unique row in the table then the code can be changed, give me a second to change my answer.

Comment: Well no, but I now assumed that ticket_id identified a unique row in the table. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, the "ticket_id" is used to group the tickets together in order to make it possible to extract groups of messages. for example: view-ticket?identifier=TICK_12943 would take all rows with the "ticket_id" value of TICK_12943 and append all the messages to the output div. The unique identifier is the ID which is auto_increment and doesnt get used, hence the "NULL" input in the INSERT INTO sql statements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54683/discussion-between-user3685539-and-riggsfolly).